# Equation for exponential function with covariate

Tags: regression, exponential-distribution, nonlinear

I understand that the formula for an exponential relationship between X and Y can be written as follows:
Y = a*exp(b*X) = exp(a+b*X)
And from there, if I want to run as a standard regression, I would take the logarithm of Y and then regression ln(Y) on X:

ln(Y) = a + b*X

I was wondering what the extension of this would be if I wanted to include a covariate. Would it be:

Y = a*exp(b1*X1)+b2*X2

And, could I then run a regression of the form:

ln(Y) = a + b1*X1 + b2*X2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial equation should have been: $\exp(a) \times \exp(bX) = \exp(a+ bX)$, so the extension to multiple variables  would be 
$exp(a) \times \exp(b_1X_1) \times \exp(b_2X_2)$.

However, in general I would recommend against log transforming the dependent variable, but instead use a model with a log link function. That way you have the advantage of the logarithm and still model the mean of the original dependent variable (the latter is no longer true if you take the logarithm of the dependent variable).  Here are some references to look at for this point:

Nicholas J. Cox, Jeff Warburton, Alona Armstrong, Victoria J. Holliday (2007) "Fitting concentration and load rating curves with generalized linear models" Earth Surface Processes and Landforms, 33(1):25--39. [link](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/esp.1523)

Santos Silva, J.M.C., S. Tenreyro 2006. "The log of gravity", The Review of Economics and Statistics 88(4):641-658. [link](http://personal.lse.ac.uk/tenreyro/jensen08k.pdf)

Jeffery Wooldridge, Econometric Analysis of Cross Section and Panel Data, 2nd ed. MIT Press, Chapter 18.

Comment: Thanks Maarten, that makes a lot of sense. One follow up question - what if I believe the interaction between two predictors has an exponential relationship with the DV, but the main effects have a linear relationship. Would I simply: (1) compute the interaction term, (2) transform this interaction term into ln(interaction), and (3) run a multiple regression with the main effects untransformed and the interaction in transformed form? My concern is that exp(a) x exp(b1X1) xexp(b2X2) assumes all parts of the model have an exponential relationship with the DV.

Comment: If you take the logarithm of $y$ or if use the log link function, then that will influence the shape of the effect for all explanatory variables, how could it be any other way?